# monthSelected event emmiter in angular material datepicker

Tags: angular-material2, angular5

I'm trying to accomplish a month only view of the [angular material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

I saw this [datepicker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-year-picker?file=app%2Fcustom-datepicker%2Fmonth-picker-component%2Fmonth-picker.component.html) adapation from angular material datepicker, which does exactly what I'm trying to do. So I looked into the code and saw this (app/custom-datepicker/month-picker-component.html):

```
<mat-datepicker #datepicker
            [touchUi]="touchUi"
            startView="multi-year"
            (yearSelected)="_yearSelectedHandler($event,datepicker)"
            (monthSelected)="_monthSelectedHandler($event,datepicker)"
            panelClass="month-picker">
```

So I tried using the monthSelected in my code to check when the user selects a month, but it doesn't seem to actually fire any event, contrary to what happens in the [datepicker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-year-picker?file=app%2Fcustom-datepicker%2Fmonth-picker-component%2Fmonth-picker.component.html) I found where the author calls for datepicker.close() inside his custom _monthSelectedHandler function.

My question is, was there some changes in the datepicker, am I doing something wrong, or is there a new way to do this? I tried searching and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

João, it's available only in material versions >= 6.0.0-beta-0 (new feature).

Comment: Thanks! I was confused about why it wasn't working for me, considering I was doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks - do you know of any workarounds to get this working in lower versions?

Comment: @orrymr I'm afraid it's not so simple (I'm not sure it's even possible).